# JOIN two tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello guys this is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM path JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE client_Id='$_SESSION[user]'
) ON INVOICE.path_Id=PATH.Id
```

I want to join two tables in the first table must have `client_Id=$_SESSION[user]`. The two tables must be joined on `path_Id`. Please help me writing this query in right way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PATH` JOIN `INVOICE` 
    ON `INVOICE`.`path_Id`=`PATH`.`Id` 
WHERE `INVOICE`.`client_Id`='$_SESSION[user]'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong in that line of code:

1. Saintize user input. By inserting a $_SESSION variable directly into
   a SQL query, you're introducing SQL Injection vulnerabilities, along
   with XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities. People can, and will do nasty
   things to your application if given a chance.
2. Never, ever select more data than you need to. Do you really need
   all columns from both tables?
3. Why two selects? A `SELECT * FROM Path p JOIN Invoice i ON i.path_id = p.id WHERE i.client_id = 1 LIMIT 1` will do the job.

Comment: XSS and CSRF (XSRF) are different.

Comment: @Lion you're right, I mentioned XSRF because if he's matching "raw" user input against the database, then chances are that he's not regenerating session IDs and he's not keeping track of unique IDs in users sessions; so it would be relatively easy to perform a XSRF attack on his application.

Comment: In CSRF attacks, an attacker typically plays a game that  users have a validated cookies already stored in their (user's) browser. The attack can be sensible when a website doesn't recognize that a request is coming from **an authorized user** instead, it only verifies that the request is coming from **the browser of an authorized user**. What an attacker does is to get that browser to make a request on his behalf performing a sensible action which the user is completely unaware of. Regenerating a session id is useful for session fixation but it's irrelevant to CSRF (or XSRF).